# FosUserBundle : access control with 2 or more roles?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, access-control

I'm using FosUserBundle for my Symfony2 project. I've added a rule for the custom `ROLE_VALIDE` to restrict the paths like `/user`. It works for the users having this role.

The problem is that I also want the admins to be able to access this path.
I've tested with both roles `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_ADMIN + ROLE_VALIDE` but I have the 403  error page.

Is there a way to add more than one role in the `access_control` ?

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user, role: ROLE_VALIDE }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about role hierarchy in your security.yml ?

**doc :** http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_VALIDE:      [ROLE_USER, ROLE_VALIDE]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_VALIDE, ROLE_ADMIN]
```

With this, if route is waiting for `ROLE_VALIDE`, `ROLE_ADMIN` is ok because is has `ROLE_VALIDE` inside it.

Comment: Oh yes, that was it ! I totally forgot about that !

Comment: Yes of course, I was just waiting for the timer to go ! Thank you.